# Linux BTF: bpftool: Failed to get EHDR from /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux

Tags: c++, linux, bpf, ebpf

I am trying to start with BPF CO:RE Development.
Using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in a VM, I needed to recompile the kernel and install pahole (from apt install dwarves) so that BTF is enabled (I set CONFIG_DEBUG_FS=y and CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=y).

So my setup is:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Kernel 5.4.0-90-generic
- bpftool --version: /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.4.0-90-generic/bpftool v5.4.148

/sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux exists and can be read out with cat.

But bpftool shows the following error:

```
$ sudo bpftool btf dump file /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux format c

libbpf: failed to get EHDR from /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux
Error: failed to load BTF from /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux: Unknown error -4001
```

From https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/blob/master/src/libbpf.h
it looks like it is *LIBBPF_ERRNO__FORMAT, /* BPF object format invalid */*
but I can not find out what's wrong.

Does anybody know where the mistake might be?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Added bpftool version

Comment: What's your version of bpftool? (`bpftool version`). Have you tried with the latest version?

Comment: It is v5.4.148, Where do I see which is the latest version?

Comment: Latest version is shipped with latest kernel sources :) If you have a local clone of the kernel sources you can [build bpftool](https://qmonnet.github.io/whirl-offload/2021/09/23/bpftool-features-thread/#source-code) from there. But note I don't know if using a newer version will fix the issue, I'm just suggesting it might be worth checking.

Comment: As I am not using the latest kernel, building bpftool from the kernel sources I used did not change anything. I can download the latest kernel and give it a try, but still it should be working with the bpftool shipped with the kernel somehow I guess :/

Comment: Did you try with the `raw` format?

Comment: Yes, raw does not change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **need to update bpftool** to support [a fallback to reading BTF as raw data if the input file is not an object file](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netdev/patch/20191018103404.12999-1-jolsa@kernel.org/). The minimum bpftool version required is v5.5 as that's the Linux release where the patch landed. In general, I would recommend to always use the latest bpftool version as there are no backports.

Comment: Hence the initial advice. Thanks pchaigno for finding the related commit! +1

Comment: Thank you! :D Another question: What is the official way to get the vmlinux.h before bpftool 5.5?

Comment: I guess it would be using libbpf in your application, just like bpftool does after the patch. I'm not aware of any other command-line tools for dumping BTF information at the moment.

Comment: Thanks!
How about pahole, which can also generate a (slightly different! :/) vmlinux.h?

Comment: Ah maybe pahole. I don't remember. Can it dump BTF, or just produce it as binary data?

Answer (score -1):

Update:
It looks like bpftool only accepts a ELF-file with the compiled runnning kernel in it, but my /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux is not:

```
$ file /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux 
/sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux: data
```

Same for /boot/vmlinuz:

```
$ sudo file /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-90-generic 
/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-90-generic: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 5.4.0-90-generic (root@elde-dev) #101+test1 SMP Tue Nov 23 16:38:41 UTC 2021, RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0xD, Normal VGA
```

Does anybody know why my /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux does not show the right format?

I found this workaround:
Using this script (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/extract-vmlinux) as suggested here (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/610672/where-is-the-linux-kernel-elf-file-located) I could get the "working" vmlinux-file which then could be read by bpftool. But this can not really be the right way for BPF CO:RE I guess... Also, in all the tutorials, bpftool is used directly with /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux.
So why do I get the wrong format?

EDIT: As suggested above, just downoad the newest linux kernel, compile bpftool from there and use that.

Comment: Good that you found a workaround. For what it's worth, `file /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux` also returns `data` on my setup where `bpftool` can read it successfully. I'm not sure what went wrong in your case though, sorry.